# Android Webview onHideCustomView when orientation changed

Tags: android, webview, react-native, android-8.1-oreo

I meet a strange issue.

I have a app which had a webview to display some articles. These articles had texts, images and videos, and this webview support playing videos in fullscreen.

This is the code of onShowCustomView and onHideCustomView. It works very well until Android 8.1.

```
@Override
public void onShowCustomView(View view, CustomViewCallback callback) {
    if (mVideoView != null) {
        callback.onCustomViewHidden();
        return;
    }
    mVideoView = view;
    mCustomViewCallback = callback;
    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    getRootView().addView(view, FULLSCREEN_LAYOUT_PARAMS);
    mWebView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    // enable orientation change 
    setOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
}

@Override
public void onHideCustomView() {
    if (mVideoView == null) {
        return;
    }
    mVideoView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    getRootView().removeView(mVideoView);
    mVideoView = null;
    mCustomViewCallback.onCustomViewHidden();
    mWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    // force portrait
    setOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}
```

And in AndroidManifest the activity looks like:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".component.ArticleActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

In Android 8.1, when playing video in fullscreen, change orientation to landscape or portrait, onHideCustomView will be called and quit fullscreen mode.

How can I fix it? Thank you

Comment: Any Solution on this?

Comment: No, but video is still playing when quit fullscreen. So it is accepted.